# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Any references to implement SSO-based authentication?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I need to implement SSO-based authentication to access a protected resource using adapters. Can anyone suggest where to start from, any references, pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation SSO is meant to allow to applications installed, who are installed on the same device and who share the same domain, to access both while logging in in only one of them (hence Single Sign On).

Read more about Device SSO in the following topics:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_device_single_sign_on.html
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_configuring_device_SSO.html